# d3.js - ordering two series by values of one of them

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have two series loaded from a CSV file. I'd like to order the two series, in the x axis, by the y values of one of them but my order routine isn't working. Someone know how to order these series??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 Teste Template</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css"> 
        div.bar {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20px;
        height: 75px; /* We'll override height later */
        background-color: teal;
        margin-right: 2px;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>

<p>Click to sort!!</p>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

    var w = 800;
    var h = 500;
    var padding = 30;

    //Define scale
    var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([padding, w-padding*2]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([h-padding, padding]);
    var z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x).ticks(10);
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y).ticks(5);

    //Define Canvas     
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",w).attr("height", h)

    //Define clipping path
    svg.append("clipPath").attr("id", "chart-area").append("rect")
    .attr("x", padding).attr("y", padding)
    .attr("width", w - padding*3).attr("height", h - padding*2);

    //Loading CSV
    d3.csv("eval_silver_standard.csv", function(error, data){
        if (error) throw error;

        // Extract yn using key
        var seriesNames = d3.keys(data[0])
        .filter(function(d) { return d !== "x"; })
        .sort();

        // Map data to cartesian tuple {x,y}
        var series = seriesNames.map(function(series) {
        return data.map(function(d) {
        return {x: +d.x, y: +d[series]};
        });
        });

    // Compute domains
    x.domain(d3.extent(d3.merge(series), function(d) { 
    return d.x; })).nice();
    y.domain(d3.extent(d3.merge(series), function(d) { 
    return d.y; })).nice();

    // X axis.
    svg.append("g").attr("class", "axis").attr("transform",
    "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")").call(xAxis)

    // Y axis.
    svg.append("g").attr("class", "axis").attr("transform",
    "translate(" + padding + ",0)").call(yAxis)

    // Append circles
    svg.selectAll(".series")
    .data(series)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "series")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); })
    .selectAll(".point")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "point")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
    .attr("r", 4);

    //On click, update order
    d3.select("p").on("click", function() {
        // Order circles
        // Code goes here
    });
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSV file:

```
x,y1,y2
0,0.85337,0.10198
1,0,0.30274
2,0.85311,0.08623
3,0.82759,0.08711
4,0.89602,0.03472
5,0.8,0.16295
6,0,0.27028
7,0.76167,0.2155
8,0.75,0.08359
9,0.81775,0.16535
10,0,0.2311
```

My sort function is not operating over, I don't know why is it

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by not operating over?

Comment: Just I'm trying to order two series and the sort method is not working. I tried a comparator but it didn't work. It's just order the two arrays in the click event, by the end of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this could be way easier if you had a point scale for positioning the circles in the x axis. Since you have a linear scale, the function I wrote has some cumbersome parts...

First things first: you have to create a function that repaint the elements in the SVG. In the following demo, it's named `draw`, and we pass the `series` array to that function.

The most important part, however, is sorting the `series` array. This, for instance, is the function for sorting the blue dots and rearranging the orange ones accordingly:

```
d3.select("#button1").on("click", function() {
    series[0] = series[0].sort(function(a, b) {
        return d3.ascending(a.y, b.y)
    }).map(function(e, i) {
        return {
            x: i,
            fx: e.fx,
            y: e.y,
            u: e.u
        }
    });
    series[1].forEach(function(d, i, arr) {
        d.x = order0.indexOf(d.fx)
    });
    draw(series);
});
```

As you can see, sorting alone won't work, because the `x` property will be sorted together. Thus, we have to sort according to `y` and then reassign `x` from 0 to 10.

For keeping the object constancy, I created an property named `u`, using `Math.random()`. There is a very little chance that two properties have the same value. However, I advise you to create your own unique property in each object (otherwise you cannot keep object constancy). The `fx` property is just to keep track of the original sequence, and `order0`/`order1` are arrays with the ordered sequence of each series.

Here is the demo, using most of your code but creating `draw` and reducing the SVG size, for better fit in a Stack snippet. Click the button to sort:

```js
var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text());

var w = 600;
var h = 200;
var padding = 30;

//Define scale
var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([padding, w - padding * 2]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([h - padding, padding]);
var z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x).ticks(10);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y).ticks(5);

//Define Canvas     
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", w).attr("height", h)

//Define clipping path
svg.append("clipPath").attr("id", "chart-area").append("rect")
  .attr("x", padding).attr("y", padding)
  .attr("width", w - padding * 3).attr("height", h - padding * 2);



// Extract yn using key
var seriesNames = d3.keys(data[0])
  .filter(function(d) {
    return d !== "x";
  })
  .sort();

// Map data to cartesian tuple {x,y}
var series = seriesNames.map(function(series) {
  return data.map(function(d, i) {
    return {
      x: +d.x,
      fx: +d.x,
      y: +d[series],
      u: Math.random()
    };
  });
});

var order0 = series[0].sort(function(a, b) {
  return d3.ascending(a.y, b.y)
}).map(function(e) {
  return e.x
});

var order1 = series[1].sort(function(a, b) {
  return d3.ascending(a.y, b.y)
}).map(function(e) {
  return e.x
});

// Compute domains
x.domain(d3.extent(d3.merge(series), function(d) {
  return d.x;
})).nice();
y.domain(d3.extent(d3.merge(series), function(d) {
  return d.y;
})).nice();

// X axis.
svg.append("g").attr("class", "axis").attr("transform",
  "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")").call(xAxis)

// Y axis.
svg.append("g").attr("class", "axis").attr("transform",
  "translate(" + padding + ",0)").call(yAxis);

draw(series);

function draw(data) {

  // Append circles
  var groups = svg.selectAll(".series")
    .data(data);

  var groupsEnter = groups.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "series")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) {
      return z(i);
    });

  var circlesEnter = groupsEnter.selectAll(".point")
    .data(function(d) {
      return d;
    }, function(e) {
      return e.u
    }).enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "point")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return x(d.x);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return y(d.y);
    })
    .attr("r", 4);

  groups.selectAll(".point").data(function(d) {
      return d;
    }, function(e) {
      return e.u
    })
    .transition()
    .duration(2500)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return x(d.x);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return y(d.y);
    })
    .attr("r", 4);

}

//On click, update order
d3.select("#button1").on("click", function() {
  series[0] = series[0].sort(function(a, b) {
    return d3.ascending(a.y, b.y)
  }).map(function(e, i) {
    return {
      x: i,
      fx: e.fx,
      y: e.y,
      u: e.u
    }
  });
  series[1].forEach(function(d, i, arr) {
    d.x = order0.indexOf(d.fx)
  });
  draw(series);
});

d3.select("#button2").on("click", function() {
  series[1] = series[1].sort(function(a, b) {
    return d3.ascending(a.y, b.y)
  }).map(function(e, i) {
    return {
      x: i,
      fx: e.fx,
      y: e.y,
      u: e.u
    }
  });
  series[0].forEach(function(d, i, arr) {
    d.x = order1.indexOf(d.fx)
  });
  draw(series);
});
```

```css
pre {
  display: none;
}

button {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1">Click to sort by Blue</button><button id="button2">Click to sort by Orange</button>
<pre id="csv">x,y1,y2
0,0.85337,0.10198
1,0,0.30274
2,0.85311,0.08623
3,0.82759,0.08711
4,0.89602,0.03472
5,0.8,0.16295
6,0,0.27028
7,0.76167,0.2155
8,0.75,0.08359
9,0.81775,0.16535
10,0,0.2311</pre>
```